# What are the ruby conventions for $LOAD_PATH for non-gems?

Tags: ruby

I have some code in a ruby project. From what I understand, library code should live in the lib folder.

so I have

```
/lib
    /mymodule.rb
    /mymodule
        /somefile.rb
```

I have been using this internal library by calling require 'relative/path/to/lib/mymodule.rb'. What is the best practice to all this library code to the $LOAD_PATH? All I want to do is say

```
require 'mymodule'
```

instead of requiring the file directly.

I have been googling around for the last 30mins, and it is not obvious to be what the best practice/convention is.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `require_relative`, which might be a bit messy if
you move files around and therefore slightly unstable. Or set
`$LOAD_PATH` in a startup/init file of your project. Just be aware of
using your own subfolder in that case to avoid name conflicts with
your gems.